# Best way to show a UIView for a duration and hide it for an interval

Tags: objective-c, nstimer, nstimeinterval

I'm making an application in xcode. I need to show an ad in a UIView for while and hide it after that. For eg. I need to show the UIView for like 15 seconds and hide it for like 30 seconds. What is the best way to do this? Will 2 NSTimers do the job? Please help.

Comment: yes nstimer is good option of it . did you tried it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ViewController.m

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self performSelector:@selector(POPUpshow:) withObject:self afterDelay:0.5];
    }

-(void)POPUpshow:(id)sender
{
    PopUpview=[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 50, 320, 430)];
    [PopUpview setBackgroundColor:[UIColor yellowColor]];
    [self.view addSubview:PopUpview];
    PopUpview.hidden=NO;

    [self performSelector:@selector(popupHide) withObject:self afterDelay:1];

}

-(void)popupHide{
    PopUpview.hidden=YES;
}
```

hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

Swift 3 version of [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24773803/best-way-to-show-a-uiview-for-a-duration-and-hide-it-for-an-interval/24774289#24774289) :

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.performSelector(#selector(self.POPUpshow), withObject: self, afterDelay: 0.5)
}

func popUpshow(_ sender: Any) {
    PopUpview = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: CGFloat(0), y: CGFloat(50), width: CGFloat(320), height: CGFloat(430)))
    PopUpview.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellow
    self.view.addSubview(PopUpview)
    PopUpview.isHidden = false
    self.performSelector(#selector(self.popupHide), withObject: self, afterDelay: 1)
}

func popupHide() {
    PopUpview.isHidden = true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This method will be helpful for you.

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:15.0f 
target:self selector:@selector(yourMethodToShowHide:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}
```

YOu can play with options like Repeat or not.
Set time interval when to call hide/show method.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use UIView animation with delay.

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.2 
                      delay:_cuToast.duration 
                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear 
                 animations:^{

                     [_cuToast.view setAlpha:0];

                 } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

                     [_cuToast.view removeFromSuperview];

 }];
```

I have implemented an android's toast like message with UIView animations.